# c# decimal property unintended truncation

Tags: c#, decimal, truncation

I recently changed a property from double to decimal and found a strange effect.
All numbers returned by the property is truncated.

This is a part of the code:

```
private int _SalesPrice;

// [ ... ]

public decimal SalesPrice
{
   get { return Convert.ToDecimal(_SalesPrice / 1000); }
   set { _SalesPrice = Convert.ToInt32(value * 1000); }
}
```

If I then in my code have something like this:

```
SalesPrice = 5.98
```

_SalesPrice will be 5980 but SalesPrice returns 5 with no decimals.

What is the reason behind that?
Using **double** instead of **decimal** works just fine.

I'm using VS2010

Comment: int a = 5980/1000 = 5

Comment: decimal a = 5980/1000 = 5

Comment: `return (decimal)_SalesPrice / 1000;`

Comment: `Using double instead of decimal works just fine.` - pretty sure it doesn't. Also WTF is downvoting all the answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing integer division, instead of decimal:

```
return _SalesPrice / 1000M;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return Convert.ToDecimal(_SalesPrice / 1000);
```

You're converting to decimal *after* the division, which will be performed on integers, i.e. truncated. Convert before division.

Additionally there's no need to use `Convert` here, just use plain casts.

Answer (score 0):

Your value is truncated, because you devide an int by an int. Change `1000` to `1000.0`. Deviding it by a double converts it before dividing.

```
public decimal SalesPrice
{
   get { return Convert.ToDecimal(_SalesPrice / 1000.0); }
   set { _SalesPrice = Convert.ToInt32(value * 1000.0); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suspect because you are doing [*integer division*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerDivision.html) in your getter. It always discards the fractional part.

- [7.7.2 Division operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691373%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

That's why your `5980 / 1000` always returns `5`.

One option can be change your integer division to floating point division like;

```
get { return Convert.ToDecimal(_SalesPrice / 1000.0); }
```